# CSS shortcut classes

Tags: css, class, shortcut, shorthand

I don't know if it's just my incompetence, but I often end up writing inline styles for elements that need special treatment like:

```
<div class="asd" style="float:right;"></div>
<a class="asd" href="#" style="font-weight:bold;"></a>
```

and I feel like this would be easier to achieve by using shortcut classes like this

```
<div class="asd right"></div>
<a class="asd bold"></a>
```

So I'm wondering if its common and accepted practice to make such shortcut class rules for such occasions? To me it seems like it would, which begs my actual question: **Are there any libraries for such shortcut rules?** So I could just drop in a css file and have these shortcuts with me wherever I go. If not I guess I could make my own, but I'm really wondering if it actually is accepted practice or does it have drawbacks? Perhaps all these rules could even be followed by !important and have a prefix of some sort to avoid collision.

Comment: Or perhaps css frameworks like bootstrap already include such wizardry by default? Can't say that I've stumbled upon these in it's documentation.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a terrible idea.

You are specifically [not using semantic labeling of your content](http://phrogz.net/css/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#semanticselector).

*Summary of why this is bad: one of the major benefits of CSS is the ability to change your appearance across your site without changing your content. If you mix presentation into your content instead of annotating it with classes that describe what it is, you can never tweak your visuals without editing your HTML (or else you'll end up with things like `.right { font-weight:bold; float:left }` if you decide that's how "those items" should appear).*

Comment: Actually found "pull-right" class from bootstrap to float right instead for writing inline css for it. But what your saying is that this is a big no-no for content but perhaps ok for layout?

Comment: @user781655 What I'm saying (in what I linked to) is that if you ever find yourself naming a CSS class based on the style you think it will effect—instead of the type of content you are labeling—then you're making a mistake.